# Google Drive Webhooks and Google forms

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms, google-api-nodejs-client, google-forms-api

So I'm trying to watch a Google form for updates. But all I get when I put in the file id is 404 not found. Does Google drives watch API not work with Google forms?

Comment: Are you watching the form or the file that the form writes to?  If memory serves there is a difference.

Comment: I only have access to the form that you can write on, I'm guessing that if I don't have access to the original file I can watch it.